# Why typeahead-on-select event firing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, bootstrap-typeahead

I use the typeahead like this :

```
<input type="text" 
       id="UxSearchAddHoc{{$index}}"  
       placeholder="search" 
       class="form-control" 
       typeahead="f as f.label for f in formulaObjects | filter:$viewValue" 
       typeahead-on-select="selectedFormulaObject()"
       style="width: calc(100% - 45px);" 
       ng-change="getAddHocObjects($index)" 
       ng-model="formulaObject" />
```

and this is my on-select event :

```
$scope.selectedFormulaObject = function () {
    $timeout(function () {
        console.log(5);
    });
};
```

But this event does not fire when I select a value from the list `selectedFormulaObject`.

Comment: typeahed-on-selet... really?

Comment: Is it the wrong method ? @DuncanLuk

Comment: Seems to be a typo in the title of your question

Answer (score 0):

I added something like this :

```
typeahead-select-on-blur="true"
```

and its working now. I learned this => The blur event occurs when the  field loses focus